# Volume calculation using Mosaic & Cut Tools

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mosaic, tools, volume, fill

I'm new to ArcGIS and I'm taking an introductory course for it. I have a problem trying to quantify the volume of a lake. The lake is enclosed by two dams which are to be extended from 1909 to 1932 m.a.s.l. I calculated the volume of the original elevation (1909m).

Now we are told to use the "Mosaic to raster" tool to merge our DTM with the raster of the dam with the new height and raster for the lake. We then have to fill the basin to the new elevation of the dam and then use the "Cut Fill" tool to quantify the volume.

I have tried this but I never get the right result. I have been at it for hours, but I do not seem to find where my mistakes lie. I tried building the mosaic with different input sequences and then filled the lake up, but to no avail. The lake either doesn't get filled fully or the dam doesn't have 1932m as height value and remains at 1909m.

Does anyone have any advice or has an idea for a different approach?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please provide a detailed list of steps (not just the tools but also the parameter values used) that you have tried .